# Color the value corresponding to a PivotItem

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook riddled with PivotTables that I have to analyze. 
Most of these Pivots only have one number I need to look at, so it's helpful to highlight them.

This is what I want the pivot to look like.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to create a macro that will go through and find "High importance" and highlight the % value (where it intersects with "Sum of Universe %") in green. This is a lot harder than I thought, as it doesn't seem like there's a way to match up the PivotField with another.

This is how far I've gotten, and then I have no idea what else to do because PivotItems doesn't have any properties I can use to do what I want. Any ideas?

```
Sub colorPivotItemValue()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim Pivot As pivotTable
        For Each Pivot In Sheet.PivotTables
            Dim pivotFieldToEdit As PivotField
            For Each pivotFieldToEdit In Pivot.PivotFields
                If pivotFieldToEdit.Name = "importance" Then
                    Dim pivotItemToEdit As PivotItem
                    For Each pivotItemToEdit In pivotFieldToEdit.PivotItems
                        If pivotItemToEdit.Name = "High importance" Then
                            pivotItemToEdit.Interior.Color = 5287936
                        End If
                    Next pivotItemToEdit
                End If
            Next pivotFieldToEdit
        Next Pivot
    Next Sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add a screen-shot of your Pivot Fields (on the right side of the scrren), names of Fields in Rows, Columns, Data parts

Comment: without seeing the pivot-table structure it's almost impossible, you can try something like `Intersect(pivotItemToEdit.DataRange.EntireRow, Pivot.PivotFields("Sum of Universe").DataRange)` , read here to get some more ideas :  https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: I have updated the screenshot @ShaiRado I tried the intersect idea, but I get error "Unable to get DataRage property" Please let me know if the screenshot helps

Answer (score 1):

I assume the range of the tables is known.

So this is how I'd do it:

```
Set the range into a variable (e.g. Set range1 = Application.Range("A1:F20")

Dim cel As Range

Dim col As Integer

Dim row As Integer

For Each cel in range1.Cells

If Cells.Value = "Sum of Universe %" Then

col = cel.Column

End If

Next cel
```

Now we should have the column as an Integer where the correct column is.

Now we should go through the same array again and find the rows.

```
For Each cel in range1.Cells

If Cells.Value = "High importance" Then

row = cel.Row

Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) {or whatever color you want}

End If

Next cel

End Sub
```

Or did I misunderstand you? There might be some syntax errors in it as I haven't tried this. Could also be possible to do it in one loop, but this is easier to understand and manage imo.

Comment: There are multiple PivotTables in each sheet, all scattered throughout. So the range is different for everyone of them...

Comment: Ah, I see. Is the row "Importance" always 2 rows to the left of "Sum of Universe %"?

Comment: Not always, I'd say 80% of the time I do though. In the updated picture on the OP you can see that `Do you eat bananas` comes before `Importance` in the "Rows" Field, the other common occurence for me is that I might switch the order of those two where `importance` comes before `do you eat bananas` and therefore it may be 3-4 rows to the left of `sum of universe2`